# Tizen Web Wearable Application: How to show my own window instead of watch time

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am working on a Web Application for `Tizen Wearable 4.0`. The application is performing many tasks e.g. Sensor data collection etc. I want to perform a *bonus* task as well.

Whenever the user sees the watch, Normally the watch time is shown to the user, I want the device to show a window of my Web Application instead of the default view of watch Time.

I couldn't find anything helpful on this. I definitely need to override any default event of the device. Please guide a bit about that specific event if available.

Answer (score 0):

Does watch time means 'watch-face'?

**It is impossible to replace watch-face view with a window of your application. When watch-face is shown.**

How about making your application watch-face application? When user set it as their watch-face, your application will be shown.

If it needs background operation, you can create a service application and make a package with watch-face application.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because the problem is that I can't show _my_ screen all the time, it's just a normal _hybrid_ application (Web UI packaged with Native Service) which will show it's screen (instead of the watch time) only when a specific flag is set.